# finding kill zones in antibiotic assays with low contrast between zones

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

This is an antibiotic assay on a petri dish:

[image: Antibiotic Assay on Petri Dish]

I'm working on a project where I'm automating the reading of antibiotic assays of the petri dish kind. In these tests, bacteria from a patient is spread over the petri dish and allowed to grow into a "bacterial lawn."  Once the bacteria cover the entire surface of the petri dish, pills either of different medicine types or the same medicine, but in different concentrations are put onto the dish and after 24 hours the kill zones, if they exist, are measured.  Kill zones represent regions where the medicine has killed off the bacteria for some radius from the pill.  How big the radius of the kill zone is determines whether that bacteria is susceptible or resistant to the medication and the different concentrations.

I've been using a training set of 20 images in a file to generalize my results.  I've been using `opencv`, `skimage`, `numpy`, `scipy` and `matplotlib` python libraries to build this program.  So far I've been able to accurately identify the petri dish rim edge with a hough circle finder and morphological gradient transform of image.  I've also been able to use `SURF` to identify the positions of the pills in the image.

**My question**:
The issue is that there isn't enough contrast between the kill zone edge and bacterial lawn to use `HoughCircleFinder` to find these circular zones.  Could anyone help me find any method to accurately identify these kill zones?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage import io,img_as_float
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import sobel
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage import io,exposure
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage import io, segmentation
from skimage.color import label2rgb,rgb2gray
from scipy import signal
import scipy
from skimage.future import graph
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max


def HoughCircleFinder(filtered_image,image):
    output = image.copy()
    gray = img_as_ubyte(filtered_image)
#   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_as_ubyte(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # detect circles in the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 5, minDist = int(0.45 * max(image.shape)), minRadius = int(0.25 * max(image.shape)), maxRadius = int(0.6 * max(image.shape)))

    # ensure at least some circles were found
    if circles is not None:
        # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            print x,y,r
            # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
            # corresponding to the center of the circle
            # filter circles that go out of view of image
            if not (image.shape[0]*0.25) < x < (image.shape[0]*0.75):
                continue
            elif not (image.shape[0]*0.25) < y < (image.shape[0]*0.75):
                continue
            else:
#               output = CropCircle(output,x,y,r)
                cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        return output

def MorphologicalGradient(img):
    kernel = np.ones((7,3),np.uint8)
#   kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
    gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
    return gradient

def SURF(img): #image1
    featurels = []
    surf = cv2.SURF(7000)
    kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(img,None)
    for i in kp:
#       print round(i.pt[0])
        featurels.append(i.pt)
    surf.hessianThreshold = 50000
    img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,None,(255,0,0),4)
    return img2,featurels


# make list of images from file

pic_list = [os.path.join("/Users/sethcommichaux/Desktop/PetriKillZone/PetriDishes/",pic) for pic in os.listdir("/Users/sethcommichaux/Desktop/PetriKillZone/PetriDishes/")]

# for loop for processing images and getting useful data
for image in pic_list[1:]:
    print image
    image1 = cv2.imread(image,0) #grayscale image
    image = cv2.imread(image) #color image
    print "number of pixels in image: ",image.size
    print "image shape (if grayscale will be 2 tuple, if color 3 or more): ", image.shape
    image = HoughCircleFinder(MorphologicalGradient(image1),image)
    print 'image data type: ',image.dtype
    plt.figure()
    io.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
    # part that finds pills
    image,features = SURF(image)
    plt.figure()
    io.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

I have used the `SURF` key points object to identify the locations of the pills, but how to find the kill zones I'm at a loss for.  Below is code for getting plots and histograms along x-axis going out from pill.

```
for row in features:
    PeakFind(image[round(row[1])])
    print image[round(row[1])]
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(range(len(image[round(row[1])])),image[round(row[1])])
    plt.show()
#   plt.figure()
#   x = plt.hist(image[round(row[0])])
print features
```

Comment: Your title and the content of your post include very little information about the actual problem you're having (distinguishing between regions in the image).  The background/motivation to your problem is not important.  As it stands, I think your question (while interesting) is *Too Broad*; please try to cut it down to a single programming concept (i.e. distinguishing between two regions of the plate).